# How many whole rectangles can you catch in a grid?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, combinatorial-geometry, rectangles

There are $n$ rectangles packed in a square; all of them are axes-parallel.
You are allowed to partition the square into a grid of cells, with $1$ or more rows and $1$ or more columns. You score a point for each cell that contains at least one whole rectangle.

What is the maximum score $s(n)$ you can get, for the worst-case initial arrangement of $n$ rectangles?

Here are two examples for $n=4$. Here:

[image]

your score is 4 (the maximum), since there are 4 cells (out of 6) that contain a whole rectangle.
However, here:

[image]

your score is only 3, since there are only 3 cells and each of them contains a whole rectangle (a cell with more than one rectangle is worth only one point).
Moreover, here:

[image]

In any grid containing more than 2 cells (e.g. $1\times 3$ or $3\times 1$ or $2\times 2$), at least 2 rectangles are cut, so at most 2 cells contain whole rectangles. This example proves that $s(4)\leq 2$.

On the other hand, it is obvious that you can always score at least $2$ by just taking any two rectangles and creating a $2\times 1$ grid. Therefore $s(4)=s(3)=s(2)=2$.

The above example can be generalized by partitioning each rectangle into $n/4$ rectangles, such that each horizontal line cuts at least $n/4$ vertical rectangles and vice-versa.
It gives an upper bound of $s(n) \leq \lceil n/2 \rceil$.

Is it always possible to score at least $\lceil n/2 \rceil$?
If not, what is the maximum possible score in the worst case?

NOTE: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/509928/29780) is related, but it considers a single cut rather than a grid.

Comment: Are the rectangles required to be congruent, or can the square be packed with rectangles of mixed sizes? Must the grid cells be square? Are the rectangle width and heights required to be multiples of the cell size?

Comment: @PaulSinclair The original rectangles need not be congruent - they can be of arbitrary sizes. Similarly, the cells in the grid need not be congruent - each row/column may have any height/width. There are no constraints on the widths and heights of the rectangles or the cells - they just need to be positive.

Comment: I'm not understanding your intent. If the cells are smaller than the rectangles, then obviously, your score is always $0$, regardless of the arrangements. If the entire square is a cell, the score is $n$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I added some more examples and explanations - I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m amazed how you can devise new problems in so well-studied domain as plain combinatorial geometry.

My first attack of the problem brought the following results.

**Proposition 1.** If $n$ is not least than [Ramsey number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Ramsey_numbers) $R(m,m)$ then $s(n)\ge m$.

*Proof.* Consider a graph whose vertices are the packed rectangles. Let any two vertices of the graph are adjacent by a red edge, if they can be separated by a vertical line and by a blue edge, if they can be separated by a horizontal line. Since any two packed rectangles can be separated either by a vertical or a horizontal line, each edge of the graph is either red or blue. Since $n\ge R(m,m)$, there are a (vertical or horizontal) direction and a set $S$ of $m$ packed rectangles such that any two distinct rectangles of $S$  can be separated by a line parallel to the direction. Then the segment, which are orthogonal projections of rectangles of $S$ parallel to the direction, have pairwise disjoint interiors. Thus the lines parallel to the direction and erected from the endpoints of the segment provided a grid with score $m$. $\square$

Since [$R(3,3)=6$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Example:_R(3,_3)_=_6), Proposition 1 implies that $s(6)=3$.

Unfortunately, Proposition 1 provides weak asymptotic lower bounds for $s(n)$, because [asymptotic bounds for $R(m,m)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Asymptotics) are exponential.

We can improve them by the following

**Proposition 2.** For any natural $n$, we have $s(n)\ge \sqrt{n}$.

*Proof*. Define a binary relation $<$ on the set $H$ of the horizontal projections of the packed rectangles, putting $I<I’$ if the right endpoint of the segment $I\in H$ lies at the left of (or coincides with) the left endpoint of the segment $I’\in H$. It is easy to check that $(P,\le)$ is a [partially ordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set). [Dilworth’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem)  implies that $H$ has either a chain of size at least $\sqrt{n}$ or an antichain $A$ of that size. In the former case similarly to the end of the proof of Proposition 1 we obtain a grid with score at least $\sqrt{n}$. In the latter case interiors of each two segments of $A$ intersect. [Helly’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_theorem) implies that all interiors of the segments of $A$ have a common point. It follows that interiors of *vertical* projections of the rectangles horizontally projected to the segments of $A$ are pairwise disjoint, and we can proceed similarly to the former case. $\square$

Proposition 2 implies that $s(5)=3$.

**Lemma 3.** For each natural $a$, $b$, and $c$, we have $s(ab+2c)\le \max\{ab,a+c,b+c\}$.

*Proof*. The claim is provided by a packing consisting of $2c$ rectangles attached to a rectangle $a\times b$ partitioned into $ab$ squares with. See below an example for $a=3$, $b=2$, and $c=2$. $\square$

[image]

**Proposition 4.** For each $a\ge 2$ we have $s(3a^2-2a)\le a^2$.

*Proof*. In Lemma 3 put $a=b$ and $c=a^2-a$. $\square$

Comment: Thanks. It seems that these bounds hold even if we limit the grid to all-horizontal or all-vertical lines, right? In this case, there is a simple upper bound of $\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil$ where the arrangement is a grid of $\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil$ by $\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil$ squares.

Comment: Proposition 4 implies that $n/2$ is not always attainable - there is an asymptotic upper bound of $n/3$, right?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi You are right in both cases. Proposition 4 implies that $s(n)\le  \left(\lceil \sqrt{n/3}\rceil+1\right)^2$ for each $n$.

Comment: I added an answer that, apparently, proves an upper bound of $s(n)\leq n/4$. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

**Proposition 5.** For each natural $k\ge 4$, $s(k^2)\le k^2/4+k$.

*Proof.* Consider the following configuration of $k^2$ squares of size $a$ contained in a big square.

[image]

Let the catching grid consists of $h$ horizontal and $v$ vertical lines, so it catches at most $(h+1)(v+1)$ squares. Removing empty grid cells, we can assume that the distance between any two parallel grid lines it at most $a$ and $h,v\le k$. This provides all squares crossed by parallel grid lines are distinct. It is easy to check that each grid line crosses at least $k-1$ squares, so the grid crosses at least $h(k-1)+v(k-1)-hv$ squares ($hv$ is subtracted because of the double count), and so it catches at most $k^2-(k-1)(h+v)+hv$ squares.
Put $h+v=2x\le 2k$. By the inequality between arithmetic and geometric means, $hv\le x^2$. So the grid cathes at most $\min\{x^2+2x+1, k^2-2(k-1)x+x^2\}$ squares. The following cases are possible:

- If $0\le x\le (k-1)/2$ then $x^2+2x+1\le (k^2+2k+1)/4$.
- If $k/2\le x\le k-1$ then $k^2-2(k-1)x+x^2\le k^2-2(k-1)(k/2)+(k/2)^2=k^2/4+k$.
- If $x=k-1/2$ then $k^2-2(k-1)x+x^2=2k-3/4$.
- If $x=k$ then $k^2-2(k-1)x+x^2=2k$. $\square$

**Corollary 6.** For each natural $n\ge 16$, $s(n)\le n/4+3\sqrt{n-1}/2+1$.

*Proof.* Pick the smallest $k$ such that $k^2\ge n$. Then $(k-1)^2\le n-1$ and $s(n)\le k^2/4+k\le 4+3\sqrt{n-1}/2+1.$ $\square$.

**Proposition 7.** When the input rectangles are all unit squares, $s(n)\geq n/4$.

*Proof.* Represent the squares by their bottom-left coordinates, $(x_i,y_i)$ for $i\in[n]$.  Partition the squares into four groups:

1. $\lfloor x_i \rfloor$ is odd and $\lfloor y_i \rfloor$ is odd;
2. $\lfloor x_i \rfloor$ is odd and $\lfloor y_i \rfloor$ is even;
3. $\lfloor x_i \rfloor$ is even and $\lfloor y_i \rfloor$ is odd;
4. $\lfloor x_i \rfloor$ is even and $\lfloor y_i \rfloor$ is even.

Pick the largest group; it contains at least $n/4$ squares. Suppose w.l.o.g. that it is group 1. Then cut at $x=1, 3, 5, ...$ and $y = 1, 3, 5, ...$; the cuts do not harm any square of group 1.

Currently, the best lower bound for arbitrary rectangles is $s(n)\geq \sqrt{n}$.
I conjecture that there should be a linear lower bound similar to $n/4$, but so far could not prove it.

EDIT: In the pattern below there are 40 squares, and it seems that the maximum score is 8, which implies an asymptotic upper bound $s(n)\leq n/5$ (not sure how to verify this):

[image]

Comment: Maybe a more complicated tiling pattern can provide a better upper bound?

Comment: @AlexRavsky not when the input rectangles are all unit squares; see Proposition 7 that I have just added. The cases of general squares and general rectangles are still open.

Comment: I just found this: http://www.tcs.tifr.res.in/events/murdering-squares-and-rectangles-using-guillotines which implies that, if we allow general guillotine cuts, then there is a lower bound $s(n) \geq n/\log(n)$ for general rectangles, and $s(b)\geq n/68$ for general squares. This does not necessarily hold for a grid.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Suppose that, in the above pattern, we replace blocks of 2-by-2 unit squares, with a single 2-size square, so that in each block of 4-by-4, we have only 10 squares (two large squares and eight small squares). Then, when cutting every other row and every other column, only 2 small squares survive, which gives a ratio of $1/5$. Is it correct?